# How to limit NaN filling in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have three pandas dataframe that containing three type of index 15 minutes period, 1 minutes and 15 seconds, I added `NaN`s to dataframes as it comes follow, and plotted theme in same figure.

Graph:
[image: Graph1]

Now I want to replace one of dataframe `NaN`s , I used `ffill()`, it worked but I need to limit filling `NaN`, I don't need what I marked red.

Graph2:

[image: Graph2]

My plot should seem like this:

[image: NOAA]
<sub>(source: [noaa.gov](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/plot_dart.php?station=23227&uom=M&width=400&height=220&start=20140830000000&end=20140903235959))</sub>

Dataframes:

http://bayanbox.ir/id/1324113030042053806?download

http://bayanbox.ir/id/774076250887409862?download

http://bayanbox.ir/id/6217190851751601245?download

Source:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# 1 minutes recorded data
data = pd.read_csv('1m.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='time')
# 15 minutes recorded data
data2 = pd.read_csv('15m.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='time')
# 15 seconds recorded data
data3 = pd.read_csv('15s.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='time')

del data['Unnamed: 0'], data2['Unnamed: 0'], data3['Unnamed: 0']

def add_nan(DF, T):
    start = DF.time[len(DF)-1]
    stop = DF.time[0]
    rng = pd.date_range(start, stop, freq=T)
    DF = DF.drop_duplicates('time').set_index('time').reindex(rng)
    return DF

data = pd.DataFrame({"1-min":np.array(data.Height[:]), "time":data.index})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({"15-min":np.array(data2.Height[:]), "time":data2.index})
data3 = pd.DataFrame({"15-sec":np.array(data3.Height[:]), "time":data3.index}) 

data = add_nan(data, '1min')
data2 = add_nan(data2, '15min')
data3 = add_nan(data3, '1S')

ax = data.plot(color='g', figsize=(10, 6))
data2.plot(ax=ax, color='b')
data3.plot(ax=ax, style='.-r')

plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't show proper plot"? If you're missing data (in the form of `NaN`s, then it won't plot anything.

Comment: Something is wrong about "data2" dataframe, the plot should seem like NOAA plot, I think 'NaN's are more than what it should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), limit parameter should set `True`

```
DataFrame.ffill(axis=0, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None)
Synonym for NDFrame.fillna(method=’ffill’)
```

[image]

This is function to add `NaN` data to dataframe, for limit `NaN` filling `limit=True` should set in dataframe:

```
def add_nan(DF, T):
    start = DF.time[len(DF)-1]
    stop = DF.time[0]
    rng = pd.date_range(start, stop, freq=T)
    DF = DF.drop_duplicates('time').set_index('time').reindex(rng)
    return DF.ffill(limit=True)
```